# How to select the specific rows using dplyr package in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

How to select the specific rows using dplyr package in R?
If column1 is NA, I want to get the value of column2, and if column2 is NA, I want to get the value of column1.

(Sample code)

```
test_data %>% 
  select(Column1, Column2) %>% 
  **?????**
```

(Example)

**test_data**

```
(Column1)|(Column2)
NA|20
NA|30
10|NA
40|NA
```

**result**

```
(Column)
      20
      30
      10
      40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)

test_data %>% transmute(col3 = coalesce(col1, col2))

  col3
1   20
2   30
3   10
4   40
```

#### Data

```
structure(list(col1 = c(NA, NA, 10L, 40L), col2 = c(20L, 30L, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use `pmin`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  transmute(col3  = pmin(col1, col2, na.rm = T))

#   col3
# 1   20
# 2   30
# 3   10
# 4   40

structure(list(col1 = c(NA, NA, 10L, 40L), col2 = c(20L, 30L, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)) -> df
```